# Remove commas from CSV file before Pandas read_csv()

Tags: python, csv, pandas

When I read in a ~35MB CSV with Pandas read_csv(), I get the an error from the CParser that there may be a malformed input file. Example is below, please see line with "PNCBANK,NATL"

UPDATE-----
When I save as a Windows CSV instead of "comma delimited" filetype with 'c' engine it runs completely fine

I read cut a sample of the CSV with commas removed from all observations and the problem persists. So this comma present in the strings below is not causing this.

> 685   201603  N   204602      0   1   O   80  44  134000  80  4.125   R   N   FRM IL  SF  61900   F116Q1000024    P   360 2   Other sellers   CENTRALMTGECO

776 201604      204603      0   1   O   46  47  108000  46  3.875   R   N   FRM CO  SF  81200   F116Q1000025    C   360 1   Other sellers   USBANKNA

693 201603      203102      0   1   S   21  44  81000   21  3.25    R   N   FRM CO  PU  81100   F116Q1000026    N   180 2   Other sellers   USBANKNA

715 201603      204602      0   1   S   75  46  63000   75  4.375   R   N   FRM CO  CO  81100   F116Q1000027    P   360 1   Other sellers   PNCBANK,NATL

691 201603      204602  30460   0   1   O   24  14  35000   24  3.875   R   N   FRM KY  SF  40300   F116Q1000028    N   360 1   Other sellers   Other servicers

758 201603      204602      0   2   I   75  36  85000   75  4.5 R   N   FRM KY  SF  40300   F116Q1000029    P   360 2   Other sellers   USBANKNA

However, when I try swapping the engine to the Python engine for this, I get a readlines error (second error below).

I believe it is because there is a column in the file that has a string with occasional commas within the string, and the file delimiter is also a comma. If this is, in fact, the problem, how can I go about replacing these commas with some other notation, if not just removing them entirely, while preserving the rest of the file. I DO know what strings have these commas, as its a particular subset of the observations for that column. Thanks!

Error with C engine for read_csv()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/paltamura/Desktop/fmData/fmData/exploratory/creditScore_descriptives.py", line 160, in <module>
    lender_by_msa = lender_PerformanceByMSA()
  File "/Users/paltamura/Desktop/fmData/fmData/exploratory/creditScore_descriptives.py", line 32, in lender_PerformanceByMSA
    date_col_fmt_dict={'firstPaymentDate': '%Y%m'}
  File "/Users/paltamura/Desktop/fmData/fmData/Load/load_loans.py", line 19, in load_data
    nrows=10000 if nrows == 'sample' else nrows
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 562, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 325, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 815, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1314, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 805, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:8748)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 827, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:9003)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 881, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:9731)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 868, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:9602)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1865, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:23325)
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

readlines() error with Python engine for read_csv()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/paltamura/Desktop/fmData/fmData/exploratory/creditScore_descriptives.py", line 160, in <module>
    lender_by_msa = lender_PerformanceByMSA()
  File "/Users/paltamura/Desktop/fmData/fmData/exploratory/creditScore_descriptives.py", line 32, in lender_PerformanceByMSA
    date_col_fmt_dict={'firstPaymentDate': '%Y%m'}
  File "/Users/paltamura/Desktop/fmData/fmData/Load/load_loans.py", line 20, in load_data
    engine='python'
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 562, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 315, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 645, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 805, in _make_engine
    self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1608, in __init__
    self.columns, self.num_original_columns = self._infer_columns()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1823, in _infer_columns
    line = self._buffered_line()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1975, in _buffered_line
    return self._next_line()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2006, in _next_line
    orig_line = next(self.data)
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Comment: paste some lines of the defective csv so we can help

Comment: If indeed this is the problem, i.e. that you have a comma as a delimiter and comma in the actual values, there is not much you can do programmatically. You could try remaking the csv with semicolons as a delimiter. If you know how many columns you have you could check which line have more commas and try to fix those by hand if there are not many.

Comment: Added example of CSV, could not paste it in very well so i broke up each line in the CSV, PNCBANK,NTL is an example of the line I suspect causing issues.

Comment: Try using a code block (the `{}` option) when pasting and if you still have problems, create an smaller example line that shows the problem. Your original problem may go away if you add `delimiter=' '` to the `read_csv` call. But you have another problem (at least in the sample data) -  the data has a variable number of columns (for instance that N in `685 201603 N 204602` verses the next line). Pandas guesses columns from the first line and if others don't match you get that error.

Comment: Save the file with quotes around those values that contain commas, and then use the `quotechar` parameter when importing the file.

Comment: @Abdou - you mean manually edit files before using them in the program? That could get tedious over time. Commas are fine within a cell of a tab or space delimited file.

Comment: @tdelaney, I am honestly not sure what the OP's file looks like (since what I see here is tab-delimited), but he or she could import the data in python with simple `open` and the `csv` module to edit the data, and then save it as a csv file with quotes where required.

Comment: Also, the file may already be quoted.

Comment: @tdelaney So this is all solved when I opened the file and saved as a Windows CSV filetype, not just Comma Delimited. Any ideas why that would make a difference here??

Comment: CSV is an umbrella term for a technique to use some character to separate data (typically comma, tab, or space) and how to escape that character if its in in the data. `read_csv` guesses the rules by peeking at the data but you can override that with additional parameters. both formats may have been correct, but `pandas` guess on one may be wrong. Sometimes you have to get into the details when reading the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a replace command: 
 cleaned_string = cleaned_string.replace(",", "")

The above command will replace all commas with "" (nothing) or with whatever you want. The string is kept as it was before but without the commas.

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be read in with read_csv() successfully beforehand? I'm aware of the string package and what an be replaced, stripped, etc. Im more concerned with what can be done as part of the parsing process behind Pandas read_csv()